# How can I use a package (such as transformers) in python script through Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: python, java, processbuilder

To connect Java and Python parts of a pipeline I am experimenting with different methods. Currently I am trying the ProcessBuilder approach using the following code in Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Tryout {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        try {
            var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python3", "tryout.py", "example string for testing purposes");
            processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
            var process = processBuilder.start();
            process.waitFor();
            System.out.println(process);
            try (var reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {

                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for python:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
import sys


print("hello from python!")
input_string = sys.argv[1]
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokens = tokenizer(input_string, padding='max_length', max_length=512, truncation=True, return_tensors="np")
print(list(tokens['input_ids'][0]))
print(list(tokens['attention_mask'][0]))
```

However, this gives me the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers'`.
Before you ask, the transformers package is installed and the python script runs fine when called from the command line.
My question is: How do I include these Modules within the JVM?

I don't fully understand the technical details of ProcessBuilder and assumed it would run in command line using my local python environment, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Check PYTHONPATH for JVM launch is same as for python from the shell it is launched from. BTW You need to put `process.waitFor()` after reading the stream.

Comment: The PYTHONPATH was indeed the issue. If we want to have this question marked as answered, you'll have to post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that PYTHONPATH for JVM launch is same as for python from the shell it is launched from. This will ensure that the environment being used when python runs as a sub-process of Java will match the environment when run directly from your shell / terminal.

**Edit**

For others with same issue, here are a few ways to check or set PYTHONPATH for Java -> Python calls. By default Java passes on the value used from its own environment variables:

```
System.out.println("getenv().PYTHONPATH="+System.getenv("PYTHONPATH"));
```

Or set PYTHONPATH just for `ProcessBuilder` launch:

```
String pypath = List.of(Path.of("somedir"), Path.of("anotherdir"))
       .stream().map(Path::toAbsolutePath).map(Path::toString)
       .collect(Collectors.joining(File.pathSeparator));
pb.environment().put("PYTHONPATH", pypath);
System.out.println("environment().PYTHONPATH="+pb.environment().get("PYTHONPATH"));
```

Check the value used in existing python scripts:

```
# import os
print("PYTHONPATH", os.getenv('PYTHONPATH'))
```